# How to resize the jframe to the screen resolution in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans-6.9

I am trying to develop application using swings in netbeans. So I want to resize my application frame to the screen resolution. Kindly help me out in this problem.

Comment: [Frame#setExtendedState](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setExtendedState(int)), you'll probably want Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH

Answer (score 4):

```
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
frame.setVisible(true);
// If you want to always keep the frame at this size
frame.setResizable(false);
```

Here is a very simple example of it, may be a good start for your application :

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MyFrame
{
    private JFrame frame;

    public MyFrame()
    {
        frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new MyFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: *"If you want to always keep the frame at this size"*, unless the user hits the "restore" button and if the "default" size of the frame is 0x0, then you've got yourself a very small, unresizable frame - nit pick ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer for this any new classes i have to create or what tell me that also.

Comment: @VaibhavAralkar The frames default size is 0x0.  Adding content to the frame and packing it, will allow the frames preferred size to establishing, meaning if you do set the frame to be un-resiable AND the user restores the frame, it won't be 0x0 any more (and hopefully) usable...

Comment: For this you would have to use `frame.pack();`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it done by the following one line code

```
     frame.setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
```

Comment: FYI This won't take into account the screen insets (task bar/dock bar)